# Kubernetes Unable to connect to the server

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster running for months on AWS.

I do not know why when I am running a `kubectl` command to my server from my deploy pipeline or my local computer I have

```
Unable to connect to the server: EOF
```

All my services seems to work well

The read operations are on the master

Kubernetes version: 1.11.7
Master version: 1.11.6

I can ssh into my master but no idea of command I can run to help

Comment: check what is generating the master IO usage

Comment: Do you still have this problem ?
Do you use `EKS` ?
Can you check if you are using the correct context: `kubectl config current-context` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use minikube take notice that when Minikube is started after than **kubectl** is configured automatically.

```
minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes cluster...
Kubernetes is available at https://192.168.99.100:8443.
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.
```

You can check and validate the cluster and context with command below:

```
$ kubectl config view
```

Comment: Let me know if it works. Please upvote, accept.